# How auto consume to new topics?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I consume data from kafka and all works perfect. But one problem - when i'm creating new topic - my script doesn't know about this. How auto refresh list of subscribed topics? I think pattern can help me, but it was mistake.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                        # auto_offset_reset="earliest",
                        group_id='my-group',
                        bootstrap_servers=["localhost:9092"],
                        )


consumer.subscribe(pattern='^pg.*')
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is not the problem. Kafka consumers (at least in Java API) will only find new topics every 5 minutes.

Check the consumer configuration properties for anything mentioning "metadata refresh"